# awk cannot print strings on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, awk

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

this gives an output:

`echo "hello world" | awk '{ print $0 }'`

this does not:

`echo "" | awk '{ print "hello world" }'`
(neither does `awk 'BEGIN{ print "hello world" }'`)

this is gnu awk on windows.

For the purpose of this question, all I'd like to do is print a string. This runs as expected on WSL/MSYS etc., but doesn't produce output when on windows (using powershell, with awk from git's linux tools and with awk installed from choco, same result. )

I couldn't find any questions regarding this specific issue on stack overflow, but perhaps there is a simple difference in how strings are handled on windows vs linux?

See [print documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html), also see [PC using documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/PC-Using.html), which treats end-of-line but doesn't mention string differences.

Comment: You need to use `echo "hello world" | awk "{ print $0 }"`

Comment: Alright, but suppose I want to actually parse something, then my stdin is already filled with input instead of the string that I want to print. How do I then also input the string to be printed?

Comment: Could you please update the question with an example?

Comment: Let's see, I wanted to have an example like this, which runs easily on linux:
```echo "complicated output to be parsed with interesting word otherword" | awk '{ if ($0 ~ ".*sasquatch") {print " there is a sasquatch"} else if ($0 ~ ".*otherword") {print "other word..."}}'```

But I can't run it on powershell anyway because of the regex in there. I'll see if I can fix that

Comment: Actually I can't give an example that will run both on bash-like and on powershell because of how powershell handles strings. This seems to be the root cause of my problem here anyway, it has nothing to do with awk. I think this makes this question moot, it can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `awk` command with *double quotes*, and escape all the in-command double quotes with `^"` *outside* of the quotes:

```sh
echo "complicated output to be parsed with interesting word otherword" | awk "{ if ($0 ~ "^"".*sasquatch"^"") {print "^"" there is a sasquatch"^""} else if ($0 ~ "^"".*otherword"^"") {print "^""other word..."^""}}"
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That does seem to be the solution to that problem, thank you! However for me it still fails  somehow, as it now gets a syntax error on the tilde, [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/4hOQDUe). I'm not sure why there is a different outcome, but answer accepted. (I'm just going to not use powershell for the task which I had in mind)

Comment: @mangelmentmanager Are you running this in the command prompt or some terminal?

Comment: I tried on the standard windows powershell app, version 5.1, build 22000, revision 282. I removed my personal profile.ps1 for clean results.

Comment: This is on windows 11, it _might_ be possible that this is an influence? I'll check on win10 later.

Comment: @mangelmentmanager In Powershell, `$` inside double quotes is a special char, you need to put a backtick in front of it. E.g. ``"`$0"``